# How do I use getbytitle with special characters?

Tags: 2013, list, rest

I have a list named "St. John's Calendar". How do I use it with SP.CamlQuery? I'm thinking I need to encode it in some way, but nothing so far has worked.

Something like:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('St. John's Calendar')/getitems
```

Comment: Does it work to do `_api/web/lists/getbytitle("St. John's Calendar")/getitems` instead?

Comment: _`How do I use it with the REST api?`_ What exactly do you want to do with the list ?

Comment: Nope, changing to double quotes doesn't help. I just want to get the items in the list.

Comment: How about _api/web/lists/getbytitle('St. John%27%27s Calendar')/getitems?

Answer (score 12):

Works with double '

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('St. John''s Calendar')/
```

Comment: I don't get it, but it does work... is there any documentation explaining that phenomenon ?

Comment: @Michael, sorry but I don't know. I used what I like to call the "hammering technique", where I rigorously pound on something until it works, a favorable approach in my world of SharePoint.

Comment: I should however note that there is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483742), with a comment pointing to the odata docs, alas it turns out as 404, but is called _AbstractTypeSystem_. I would also note that I got a successful try quite early, as this approach is not uncommon practice in programming

Comment: The peculiarity is actually mentioned [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398071) **One of these rules is that single quotes within string literals are represented as two consecutive single quotes.**

Answer (score 1):

You should switch back to Id in that case.

For example: First query

```
https://siteurl/_api/web/lists
```

and note down the guid of the list, then use

```
https://siteurl/_api/web/lists('6678c589-4a6b-4625-be62-ad5ddf97f1a7')/items
```

will give you the items

Comment: Yes, I will do this if I have to. But I want to know if there is a way of using the list name.

Comment: I think Amal is right. The single quote in your list name `St. John's Calendar` must be causing the problem. So, try using List id.

Comment: To clarify, I want to know if I can use the list name in some way, not switch to using guids.

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to get all the items of the list. You can try `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('St. John's Calendar')/items` .

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx#bk_ListCollectionGetByTitle) for other options for `getbytitle` method.

Comment: This doesn't work because of the special characters in the list name.